# DataGrid Does Not Shows The Row For New Items

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid, wpftoolkit

I'm dealing with the WPF DataGrid. I need it to show the empty row for new items when I start editing a new row. I want this because sometimes the user just clicks outside of the datagrid without completing the information of the row.

A solution I tried was commiting row changes when the grid lost focus BUT the event is kind of wrong because it loses focus to any control INSIDE itself.

How do I commit row changes when the data grid lose focus?

Thanks!

Comment: In WPF datagrid, the new row gets added into the items source if we press Enter isnt it?

Comment: Yeah but if I focus on a control other than the grid, the row is still in editing mode. So, if the user would want to insert a new row he would have to click the row in edit mode the  press enter and then focus on the new row. That's a lot of steps to figure out.

Comment: Honestly focus based commit on WPF datagrid can be irritating in certain cases. They become a little unmanagable if pre-commit validations come into picture. I remember falling back to using the "Enter" approach. It was much manageable.

Answer (score 1):

I hope the below code will help.

```
 private void grdEmp_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!isManualEditCommit)
        {
            isManualEditCommit = true;
            DataGrid grid = (DataGrid)sender;
            grid.CommitEdit(DataGridEditingUnit.Row, true);
            isManualEditCommit = false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354916/what-is-the-proper-way-to-handle-multiple-datagrids-in-a-tab-control-so-that-cell/6467171#6467171).  The specifics are different, but basically, it sets up a behavior to commit changes when the DataGrid loses focus.  I was able to tweak this a bit to resolve issues I was having.