# DeferRefresh Error in C#

Tags: c#, list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the proper way to handle multiple datagrids in a tab control so that cells leave edit mode when the tabs are changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354916/what-is-the-proper-way-to-handle-multiple-datagrids-in-a-tab-control-so-that-cel)

When I'm binding my list to data grid after updating of data grid it gives me error like

```
"DeferRefresh' is not allowed during an AddNew or EditItem transaction"
```

so how can i overcome my problem please any one help me.

Thanks,
@nagaraju.

Comment: This is not a Duplicate since  it has occurred in  different scenarios