# WPF DataGrid not exiting edit mode

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` displaying several rows and columns of data, each is bound to its own `Property`. The `DataGrid` is NOT on a `TabControl` but whenever the window that it lives on is closed and reopened I get the error message: `'DeferRefresh' is not allowed during an AddNew or EditItem transaction.` *ONLY IF* there were validations issues with one or more of the `DataGrid`'s cells.

**For example:** The property bound to the `DataGrid`'s `cell` is a `double` and the user enters "hello", of course then `WPF's` automatic red border is displayed around the `cell`. Now, if the user were to close the window, and reopen it the error would occur.

*I know why* the error is being thrown, because the `cell` is not leaving "edit mode".

**How can I resolve this error?**

**Other Notes:**

- I have looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354916/what-is-the-proper-way-to-handle-multiple-datagrids-in-a-tab-control-so-that-cel) but that is pertaining to a `DataGrid` on a `TabControl` (which mine is not).
- I have attempted to limit the user's input so that if the `Cell` requires a `double` or then only accept a `double`, but the problem is there are no good ways to limit the number of decimal points (".") that the user can insert. I am controlling user input through `PreviewTextInput` and only allowing 0-9 and ".".

---

**Exception Detail** (if this helps)

```
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
  Message='DeferRefresh' is not allowed during an AddNew or EditItem transaction.
  Source=PresentationFramework
  StackTrace:
       at System.Windows.Data.CollectionView.DeferRefresh()
       at System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection.SetCollectionView(CollectionView view)
       at System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl.OnItemsSourceChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
       at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType)
       at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpressionBase.Invalidate(Boolean isASubPropertyChange)
       at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.TransferValue(Object newValue, Boolean isASubPropertyChange)
       at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.Activate(Object item)
       at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.AttachToContext(AttachAttempt attempt)
       at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.MS.Internal.Data.IDataBindEngineClient.AttachToContext(Boolean lastChance)
       at MS.Internal.Data.DataBindEngine.Task.Run(Boolean lastChance)
       at MS.Internal.Data.DataBindEngine.Run(Object arg)
       at MS.Internal.Data.DataBindEngine.OnLayoutUpdated(Object sender, EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.fireLayoutUpdateEvent()
       at System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayout()
       at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.SetLayoutSize()
       at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.set_RootVisualInternal(Visual value)
       at System.Windows.Window.SetRootVisualAndUpdateSTC()
       at System.Windows.Window.SetupInitialState(Double requestedTop, Double requestedLeft, Double requestedWidth, Double requestedHeight)
       at System.Windows.Window.CreateSourceWindow(Boolean duringShow)
       at System.Windows.Window.ShowHelper(Object booleanBox)
       at REACT.ViewModel.ReceiverListViewModel.ShowWindow(String name) in C:\Users\jcarroll42\Documents\Sandbox\REACT\SW\Source\ViewModel\ReceiverListViewModel.cs:line 238
       at REACT.Commands.ShowWindowCommand.Execute(Object parameter) in C:\Users\jcarroll42\Documents\Sandbox\REACT\SW\Source\Commands.cs:line 137
       at MS.Internal.Commands.CommandHelpers.CriticalExecuteCommandSource(ICommandSource commandSource, Boolean userInitiated)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick()
       at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
       at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.ReRaiseEventAs(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args, RoutedEvent newEvent)
       at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
       at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(RoutedEventArgs args)
       at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
       at System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(InputReport inputReport)
       at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr hwnd, InputMode mode, Int32 timestamp, RawMouseActions actions, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 wheel)
       at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, WindowMessage msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
       at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
       at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
       at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
       at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WrappedInvoke(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
       at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
       at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
       at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
       at System.Windows.Application.Run()
       at REACT.App.Main() in C:\Users\jcarroll42\Documents\Sandbox\REACT\SW\Source\obj\x86\Debug\App.g.cs:line 0
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

I'll be happy to provide anymore information if needed.

Comment: Are you using new Window / datagrid instance every time.?

Comment: I solved a similar problem by calling buttonBlah.Focus() inside the Window Closing event, this forces the LostFocus event to fire on the cell. Not pretty I know ... Another solution is to only allow the Window to be closed using Buttons "Save" and "Cancel".

Comment: @JordanCarroll try handling the Window_Closing Event and clearing the datagrid data source. but as its a new grid instance every time, this issue shouldn't be happening at all.

Comment: Well, the issue is apparently a well known bug. The problem is that the `cell` won't leave edit mode (if there is invalid text) because the text does not match the `type` of the Property. It makes sense, but it is a bug. The problem isn't that it is not losing focus either. It apparently was fixed in 4.5, but that does me no good. So far, I don't think there are any great fixes or workarounds.

Comment: I have the same problem with .NET 4.7.1, and it got worse than it was in the beginning. Now it never cancels or commits edit mode, not only if it has validation errors. I see that LostFocus event is fired for the cell, but it seems to be to late, only the workaround mentioned by @Jack is working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug that was fixed with .NET Framework 4.5+. Unfortunately, for those of us stuck with previous versions the error is still a problem. The best solution I have found is to simply bind the `DataGrid` to `properties` with type `string`. That way, full control over user input is available. With full control, the user should not be able to trigger any errors, and the`DataGrid` will not crash the program.

Comment: I have this exact problem with .NET 4.5.1.

Comment: @l33t Ever fix it?  I too am running .NET 4.5 and am still seeing this.

Comment: @Jordan, can you link to the doc showing when exactly this was fixed/addressed?  Was it in 4.5 or 4.5.1, 4.5.2, etc?  I couldn't find anything on the searches that it was even addressed let alone fixed.

Comment: @MarquelV, no fix yet :(

Comment: I am facing the same problem even with .net 4.6.

Answer (score 12):

You can try to force datagrid into cancelling edition when you need it:

```
myDatagrid.CommitEdit(); 
myDatagrid.CancelEdit();
```

This worked for me, i had a similar issue when reordering rows.

Comment: Where do you put that code? I've tried to put it on the event raised by the button used to close the window but it does not solve the issue for me

Comment: @FrancescoDS Hey i was having a similar issue, and the error was being triggered by a dataGrid.ItemsSource = data; line. I literally put it right before the line that was causing the error and it worked for me - for me it was caused by an erroneous double click on a cell in the datagrid (the double click was making the program believe the user was trying to edit the contents of a cell but that was not the intention of the users)

Answer (score 1):

I was having this issue .NET 4.5.1 and this was the only thing that worked for me.

```
    ListCollectionView lcv = (ListCollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(MyDatagrid.ItemsSource);


                if (lcv.IsAddingNew)
                    lcv.CommitNew();
                if (lcv.IsEditingItem)
                    lcv.CommitEdit();
```